# dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4 because no repositories are defined

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

I have already checked lots of questions related to this question but nothing working out

**Project dependency Build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
}}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

}

Error
A problem occurred configuring project ':*********'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration '::classpath'.
> Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :*************

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Can you please help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra curly brace after `dependencies {}` block, move it to the end of the file So that `allprojects {}` gets included as a child of `buildscript {}`